# How to use some elements into owl slider and animate it?

Tags: jquery, html, css, owl-carousel, animate.css

I use owl slider in my website skin .My codes such as this:

```
<div id="slider" data-section="home">
  <div class="owl-carousel owl-carousel-fullwidth">
  <div class="item">
     <img src="images/iphone-1.jpg" />
     <div>
        <h2>My Industrial Group</h2>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
     <img src="images/iphone-2.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
     <img src="images/Sahand-Industrial-Group-Site_1400_638.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
     <img src="images/wiredglass-1_1400_638.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Now I want add `h2` tags into slider and animate it. Position of `h2` tags must be left button.

How to do this?

Comment: Please write what have you tried so far.

Comment: I want add into div tags with item class (  <div class="item">) some h2 tag such as ( <div>
                    <h2>My Industrial Group</h2>
                </div>) and display this elements on the images and animate h2 tags

Comment: It is not a place to give advice. You have to write code and if you are facing issue then other can help to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add an `h2` tag into `.item`
2. Add `position:absolute` to `h2` and set `bottom` and `left` as you wish.

**All together** (watch this in full screen mode)

```js
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
  loop:true,
  margin:10,
  nav:true,
  items:1
})
```

```css
h2 {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:5px;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="owl-carousel">
  <div class="item"><h2>Heading 2 - Slide 1</h2><img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_caramel.jpg" /></div>
  <div class="item"><h2>Heading 2 - Slide 1</h2><img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_donut.jpg"/ ></div>
</div>
```

http://jsbin.com/zotato/edit?html,css,js

Comment: Mosh Feu : Thank you .